# Google Workspace Add-on bug - "JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error. Error code INTERNAL."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-logging, google-workspace-add-ons

I have developed a Google Workspace Add-on for Google Sheets that has been available on the Google Workspace Marketplace for about 1.5 years with a lot of active users.

I recently updated some features and 2 new errors have begun popping up that I can't seem to debug. They show in my Google Cloud Console logs and error reports as follows:

```
We're sorry, the JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error. Error code INTERNAL.
0[unknown file]([unknown function])
```

and

```
Exceeded maximum execution time
0[unknown file]([unknown function])
```

From what I understand from the small amount of information available about this online is that something is timing-out in one of my custom functions. The issue is these bugs won't give me any useful information, such as a specific line in my code and I can't seem to see any point at which the functions could hang. Is it possible that this error occurs when a large number of users are accessing the add-on at once?

Has anyone here experienced the same issue that could explain how to get more information on the issue to even begin debuggint the root cause. Or if there is a specific technical assistance support line I could use for Google Developers I'm all ears, there just doesn't seem to be one available that I could find.

Thanks!

Comment: The question needs more focus. If you decide to focus it on "custom functions", please add a [mcve]. P.S. Regarding Google Apps Script support see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support, for troubleshooting see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. I know the question is vague. I had read that support link you shared and it directs Apps Script developers to use Stack Overflow with the google-apps-script tag, there doesn't seem to be another support option. I would include minimal reproducible code if it were available but the point of the query is I can't reproduce it and I don't know what those errors really represent as there's no documentation that covers them (I have read that troubleshooting guide as well and they're not covered there). They seem to be generated by the JS engine yet there's no clear reasoning.

Comment: If you aren't able to make this question a good fit for this site and/or if you want to have a discussion about your issue consider to use the Google Apps Script community (the support link provided in my previous comment has links to that community).